# Replace the text of a button on button click from a GridView with a custom adapter?

Tags: android, gridview, android-adapter, android-viewholder

I have a GridView which is created via a custom GridViewAdapter which extends a BaseAdapter to create its view. Each cell in the GridView is represented by a button.

Inside of the View getView method, I use a ViewHolder to cache the button.

```
holder.gridPanel.setText(panel.getNumberPanel());
```

Then I tried to apply an OnClickListener to this button however the text of the button does not seem to change even though the Toast notification returns the correct value to set the new text of the button to.

```
holder.gridPanel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Toast.makeText(context, panel.getAlphabetPanel(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            holder.gridPanel.setText(panel.getAlphabetPanel());

        }
    });
```

What is the correct way of changing the text of a button which has been stored inside of a ViewHolder?

Code:

```
static class ViewHolder {
    Button gridPanel;

}

public class GridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    ArrayList<Panel> panelList;
    Panel panel;

public GridViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Panel> panelList){
    this.context = context;
    this.panelList = panelList;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return panelList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return panelList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return panelList.indexOf(getItem(position));
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.game_grid_item_layout, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.gridPanel = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.grid_AlphabetPanel);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    panel = panelList.get(position);
    holder.gridPanel.setText(panel.getNumberPanel());


    holder.gridPanel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            Toast.makeText(context, panel.getAlphabetPanel(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            holder.gridPanel.setText(panel.getAlphabetPanel());

        }
    });



    return convertView;
}


// below methods are in a different activity

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
    ArrayList<Panel> panelList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> alphaList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> numberList = new ArrayList<>();
    alphaList.add("A");
    alphaList.add("B");
    alphaList.add("C");
    alphaList.add("D");
    alphaList.add("E");
    numberList.add(Integer.toString(1));
    numberList.add(Integer.toString(2));
    numberList.add(Integer.toString(3));
    numberList.add(Integer.toString(4));
    numberList.add(Integer.toString(5));

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        String alp = alphaList.get(i);
        String numb = numberList.get(i);
        Panel panelObject = new Panel(alp, numb);
        panelList.add(panelObject);

    }

    GridView panelGrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView_Panel);
    GridViewAdapter gridViewAdapter = new GridViewAdapter(this, panelList);
    panelGrid.setAdapter(gridViewAdapter);

}
```

Comment: where are you setting the Panel object values? and have you made sure that panel.getNumberPanel() and panel.getAlphabetPanel() are not returning you the same data for this position?

Comment: @inner_class7 I am creating an ArrayList of alphabets and numbers as a Panel object in the main activity and passing it onto the adapter. The getNumberPanel() and getAlphabetPanel() only contains A = 1, B = 2 and I have checked the data since the number is the text on the button and clicking on the button generates a Toast with the alphabet (but does not change the text of the button)

Comment: are you calling setNumberPanel(1) & setAlphabetPanel(A) ? or are you setting both to 1? it seems like you must have your data messed up because your adapter is not wrong. Can you please share this code where it is being set, and show the full adapter

Comment: @inner_class7 I have added in extra code, I do not think I went wrong since the Toast messages show the correct values

Answer (score 0):

So I came to an answer if anyone was wondering.

Calling the setOnClickListener when the ViewHolder is being initialised works whereas doing it outside of the loop will not allow the data to be changed.

In code:

```
if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.game_grid_item_layout, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.gridPanel = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.grid_AlphabetPanel);
        holder.gridPanel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                holder.gridPanel.setText(panel.getAlphabetPanel());
            }
        });

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
```

Comment: this is not the issue your having... I will post the correct solution. It has to do with your Adapter, i was not right when i said you had a problem.